# To exclude the generated code from sonar analysis on Quality violation

Tags: sonarqube

The generated code is present in a separate target folder path like: `target/generated-sources/fod1/fod2/*.java`

I have been trying several option but in vain please help.

```
<properties>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/generatedsources/fod1/fod2/**/*.java</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

I have tried the option from one of the posts also `**/*generated*`

Answer (score 13):

See the documentation in the General Settings > Exclusions page. The pattern `file:**/generated-sources/**` will do the job if you're not using a too old version of SonarQube.

Comment: Is this the proper way ??  <sonar.exclusions>file:/generated-sources/</sonar.exclusions>

Comment: Yes it is. Be careful, in the provided example there are two stars before and after the pattern '/generated-sources/'.

Comment: I am a bit confused now ... Am i suppose to give "file:**/generated-sources/**"  or  " file:/generated-sources/ "  as the pattern in the sonar.exclusions tag

Comment: hi, I tried with  <sonar.exclusions>file:/generated-sources/</sonar.exclusions> . It is not able to exclude :(

Comment: "file:**/generated-sources/**" is the pattern to be used and this is documented at the end of Settings > Exclusions page. This feature is available since SonarQube 3.5, see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2760

Answer (score 1):

On SonarQube 5.4, the exclusions for duplications are on General Settings > Analysis Scope, on the Duplications tab