# Maven, SonarQube & Exclusions not working as expected

Tags: sonarqube

Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585688/3639934 I've put the following in my POM to exclude generated source files, which exist in `target/generated-sources/x/y/z`.

```
</properties>
    <sonar.exclusions>file:**/generated-sources/**</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

In my logfile I see no files excluded, however there are files in my project's directory under `target/generated-sources/x/y/z`.

```
[10:14:39.346] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[10:14:39.346] Test paths: src/test/java
[10:14:39.347] Binary dirs: target/classes
[10:14:39.348] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
[10:14:39.348] Index files
[10:14:39.363] Excluded sources: 
[10:14:39.363]   file:**/generated-sources/**
[10:14:39.484] 47 files indexed
[10:14:39.487] 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

I'm using SQ 5.1.1, Maven 3.2.3, Java 8.

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: this is not my area of work, but my 2 cents would be that you are excluding files, so a trailing `/*` might be missing

Comment: According to [this comment](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2760?focusedCommentId=37967&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-37967) there should be no /* be required at the end, but I will try this either.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with `file:**/generated-sources/**/*` also.

Comment: Has no one done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the log fooled me. The generated-sources are no part of the analysis right from the start, so it did not show up any excluded files.
When I change the exclusion pattern to match a file from say "src/main/java" it logs the expected exclusion (and does not analyze the file.)